# jquery добавить get параметр

Tags: javascript, jquery

при выборе select скрипт постоянно добавляет параметр, как его раз добавить и при следующих изменениях просто менять?

```
<select id="sort_by">
            <option value="sort-asc" id="sort-asc">наименьшая цена</option>
            <option value="sort-new" id="sort-new">новинки</option>
            <option value="sort-Alfavit" id="sort-Alfavit">по алфавиту</option>
        </select>

 $(document).on('change', '#sort_by', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var val = $("#sort_by").val();
               history.pushState(null, null,  window.location+'&sort='+val);
            });
```

Comment: `.on()` заменить на `.one()` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, все так же лепит параметры в url, что примечательно без window.location+ один раз добавляет, но убирает другие параметры

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всех популярных браузерах кроме IE:

```
/* ... */
const url = new URL(window.location);  // == window.location.href
url.searchParams.set('sort', val); 
history.pushState(null, null, url);    // == url.href
/* ... */
```

Comment: так работает =)

Comment: @аноним, конечечно работает)) И главное - нет потребности страдать с `?` и `&`, формируя итоговый href.